# How to access a java Derby database? I could really do with a few helpful pointers

Tags: java, database, database-design, database-schema, derby

I am new to using Derby and databses in eclipse, and I have become a tad lost and in need to a bit of help. I have established a database connection, created a new database, and a new schema, within which I have some tables containing some test data. I don't have any problem with the sql queries to select the relevant data. The problem I have is getting to a point where I can use queries. I am trying to create a class which connects to the database, and for testing purposes, uses a simple query to select some data. This is what I have so far:

```
public void getExerciseInfo() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost/c:/TestDatabase");
        PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * from TESTSCHEMA.TESTTABLE");

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String name= resultSet.getString("NAME");
            String type = resultSet.getString("TYPE");
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(type);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        close();
    }
}
```

All I am trying to do is output the data in the table to the console, but I cant even do this simple task :( Im guessing my connection url is invalid, is it supposed to be the file path to the database folder in my eclipse workspace?

Anyhow, I am very lost, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {}` will swallow exceptions. Don't do that. Instead, log it or use `e.printStacktrace()`. And then update the question with the exception, if you don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look over: http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html ? You seem to be using the network server but your db URL is wrong.

Comment: hi, no, i hadn't found that tutorial, but it looks like I should be able to fix it with it, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are *not* running the Derby server, you can establish an [embedded database connection](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/devguide/rdevdvlp22102.html)  or use an [`EmbeddedDataSource`](http://db.apache.org/derby/javadoc/publishedapi/jdbc3/org/apache/derby/jdbc/EmbeddedDataSource.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673728/my-programs-action-listener-wont-work/6673788#6673788).